# Covenant of Prophets? can someone explain this ayat

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophets

> - And (remember) when Allah took the Covenant of the Prophets, saying: "Take whatever I gave you from the Book and Hikmah (understanding of the Laws of Allah, etc.), and afterwards there will come to you a Messenger (Muhammad SAW) confirming what is with you; you must, then, believe in him and help him." Allah said: "Do you agree (to it) and will you take up My Covenant (which I conclude with you)?" They said: "We agree." He said: "Then bear witness; and I am with you among the witnesses (for this)." [3:81](https://quran.com/3/81) - Translation by Muhsin Khan.

how come Rasul (Muhammad(S)) went to each Prophet in past and did confirmation and how Prophets of past helped Muhammad(S) as mentioned in ayat?

**My understanding so far**: If Allah says one Messenger went and did confirmation of The Book and Wisdom with all Prophets then we can't say 'any' one of the messenger went from 300+ messengers (there is no proof in Quran about 300+ messengers). Allah only talked about 19 Prophets and few messengers in Quran. Prophet are normally Humans in Quran. Messenger is either a human or Prophet or Angel. It may be possible that Muhammad(S) went as an Angel or Spirit (Allah knows best). Quran doesn't say Muhammad(S) was last, but Khatam-un-Nabiyeen (Seal/Confirm of Prophets).He is confirming what Prophets got.
In Surah Isra/1 Allah took his servant in night from A to B we don't know how but Allah took him. We can assume i think. 
If we assume Muhammad(S) as last then we would be confused how the Last one went to each Prophet? Khatum means not last it means Seal/Stamp. 2:7 Allah has set a seal upon their hearts (Khatum word is used). If we say he was seal/stamp/confirmation, then we can say in 3/81 Muhammad(S) was the one that did confirmation with Prophets.

Allah knows best. I would love to hear the answer from someone that is correct understanding of this ayat according to Quranic ayats.

Comment: Your understanding is simply speaking wrong nowhere the verse pretends or says that Muhammad went to each or any of the other prophets or messengers. I guess your question is already covered in [What is the meaning of meethaq taken from the prophets](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33674/what-is-the-meaning-of-meethaaq-taken-from-the-prophets-anbiaa/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyse the verse step by step:

- > وَإِذْ أَخَذَ اللَّهُ مِيثَـقَ النَّبِيِّيْنَ لَمَآ ءَاتَيْتُكُم مِّن **كِتَـبٍ** وَ**حِكْمَةٍ** ثُمَّ جَآءَكُمْ **رَسُولٌ** مُّصَدِّقٌ لِّمَا مَعَكُمْ لَتُؤْمِنُنَّ بِهِ وَلَتَنصُرُنَّهُ قَالَ ءَأَقْرَرْتُمْ وَأَخَذْتُمْ عَلَى ذلِكُمْ إِصْرِى قَالُواْ أَقْرَرْنَا قَالَ فَاشْهَدُواْ وَأَنَاْ مَعَكُمْ مِّنَ الشَّـهِدِينَ
- > And [recall, O People of the Scripture], when Allah took the covenant of the prophets, [saying], "Whatever I give you of the Scripture and wisdom and then there comes to you a messenger confirming what is with you, you [must] believe in him and support him." [ Allah ] said, "Have you acknowledged and taken upon that My commitment?" They said, "We have acknowledged it." He said, "Then bear witness, and I am with you among the witnesses."
  >   ([3:81](https://legacy.quran.com/3/81) -SAHIH INTERNATIONAL Translation)
- > And (remember) when Allah took the Covenant of the Prophets, saying: "Take whatever I gave you from the Book and Hikmah (understanding of the Laws of Allah, etc.), and afterwards there will come to you a Messenger (Muhammad SAW) confirming what is with you; you must, then, believe in him and help him." Allah said: "Do you agree (to it) and will you take up My Covenant (which I conclude with you)?" They said: "We agree." He said: "Then bear witness; and I am with you among the witnesses (for this)." 
  >   (3:81 -MUHSIN KHAN Translation)

This verse says Allah has taken a covenant of the prophets ()!

Prophets unlike Messengers actually don't have the duty to spread Allah's message, even if they may get revelation (wahy), their duty is to live according to the message at hands and apply it in their daily life and (only) teach it when asked -so they don't need to be actively preaching!
Messengers in contrast must preach the message that's their mission and some of them have been given a (new) scripture (else why would we talk about Zabur (Psalms?), sohof -papers- Ibrahim and Musa, the Torah and Injeel beside the Qur'an and why would the Qur'an quote some of them in the same verse).

What is the covenant Allah took?
Let's read and make some conclusion from the above text:

> <sub>SAHIH INTERNATIONAL translation says:</sub>
>   "**Whatever I give you of the Scripture**
>   <sub>MUHSIN KHAN translation says:</sub>
>   **"Take whatever I gave you from the Book"**

- A prophet () has been given "a scripture" (parts of it) not "the scripture" (the whole), so he has knowledge of parts of the message of Allah for example tawheed! But not all of it.
- Note that that both translations here may lead to a somewhat inaccurate meaning as scripture or book are meant generally not a specific book so saying the book or the scripture actually doesn't go along with the Arabic original (see my explanation on Arabic terms later)!

> <sub>SAHIH INTERNATIONAL translation says:</sub>
>   and **wisdom** and
>   <sub>MUHSIN KHAN translation says:</sub>
>   and **Hikmah** (understanding of the Laws of Allah, etc.), and

- Beside knowledge of the scripture prophets have been given wisdom (or Arabic hikmah which comes from hukm: how to decide, give a verdict etc.): this might mean how to apply the scripture, and generally about rulings and how to apply them, about manners -as a part of the message- etc.

> <sub>SAHIH INTERNATIONAL translation says:</sub>
>   **then there comes to you a messenger confirming what is with you**,
>   <sub>MUHSIN KHAN translation says:</sub>
>   **afterwards there will come to you a Messenger (Muhammad SAW) confirming what is with you**

- now if a prophet or many prophets was/were alive and a messenger came (according to SAHIH INTERNATIONAL translation which is more close to the truth as it doesn't exclude other messengers, while MUHSIN KHAN say it is only Muhammad () which certainly applies, but is too restricted). And if this messenger was confirming the message they have got, or in what they have from the scripture or wisdom.
  Note here are many "if"'s all these are conditions or criteria that must be fulfilled simultaneously.

> <sub>SAHIH INTERNATIONAL translation says:</sub>
>   you **[must] believe in him and support him**."
>   <sub>MUHSIN KHAN translation says:</sub>
>    you **must, then, believe in him and help him**."

- this actually is an essential part of covenant if all the above conditions apply the prophets () are asked to follow (believe) and help (support) the messenger.
- Note that Arabic here uses strong words of to emphasize the necessity to follow and support by adding an invocation to each verb meaning they **must support** and **must follow** no matter what.
- Now let's assume their came a false "Messenger" with a false message (going against the scripture or at least not confirming it at all, for example allowing zina) would the prophets need to follow him? **No** as this men is preaching something which goes against what the prophet had in his scripture.
- Or let's assume prophet x lived 60 years and died without meeting or hearing from any new messenger who came with a new revelation or a message confirming his message and preaching Allahs message would this prophet have fulfilled the covenant? **Yes**, even if he didn't need to as during his life no new messenger was sent with a message.
- The MUHSIN KHAN translation practically applies to all prophets as none of them met Muhammad () as far as we have been told and taught. While the SAHIH INTERNATIONAL translation has some examples in the qur'an for example the prophet Yahya () was alive when 'Isa has brought a "new message" (the injeel) and he supported 'Isa.
  'Isa in the Qur'an when addressing bani Isara'il says:

  > And [I have come] **confirming what was before me of the Torah** and to make lawful for you some of what was forbidden to you. And I have come to you with a sign from your Lord, so fear Allah and obey me. ([3:50](https://legacy.quran.com/3/50))

  so 'Isa is an example of a messenger who came after a whole lot of messengers and prophets and who confirms their teaching, but brought some ease -in the religion- with him (by making lawful what was forbidden before his "new message"). The same may apply to Ibrahim () and Lut () and Ya'qub and Yousuf etc.

> <sub>SAHIH INTERNATIONAL translation says:</sub>
>   [ Allah ] said, "Have you acknowledged and taken upon that My commitment?"
>   <sub>MUHSIN KHAN translation says:</sub>
>   Allah said: "Do you agree (to it) and will you take up My Covenant (which I conclude with you)?"

- This verse is the part that covers the acknowledgement and confirmation of the covenant. Allah who inspired his prophets () by revelation also asked them to confirm that they would support a messenger that actually fulfils the given criteria or conditions. 
  And in the next part of the verse the Qur'an shows their agreement or affirmation:

  > <sub>SAHIH INTERNATIONAL translation says:</sub>
  >   They said, "We have acknowledged it."
  >   <sub>MUHSIN KHAN translation says:</sub>
  >   They said: "We agree."

Before quoting the final and important words that Allah is witness of this covenant which means He expects from each prophet () to fulfil his duty **if** the conditions are met:

> <sub>SAHIH INTERNATIONAL translation says:</sub>
>   He said, "Then bear witness, and I am with you among the witnesses."
>   <sub>MUHSIN KHAN translation says:</sub>
>   He said: "Then bear witness; and I am with you among the witnesses (for this)."

As seen nowhere the verse says that Muhammad or any Messenger had to meet the prophets () or did take the covenant or even need to travel between time and space or whatever. It says that Allah asked every prophet () to stand by side by side with any messenger that they might meet while they are alive if and only if this messenger first confirms what they have in hand of the scripture and wisdom and secondly has been given the order to spread the message. This doesn't need any Angels, as humans can do this task easily.

Also note that the Qur'an uses the words:

- كِتَـبٍ "Kitabin" a book or a scripture or a message (in generally not exclusively) instead of الكتاب "al-Kitab" meaning the book, the message or the scripture (exclusively).
- حِكْمَةٍ "Hikamatin" a wisdom (also as a plural and in general without exclusion) instead of الحِكْمَة "al-Hikmah" the wisdom (exclusively).
- رَسُولٌ "Rassulun" referring to a messenger (generally not exclusively) not الرَسُولُ "Ar-Rassulu" referring to one special messenger (exclusively)

Note that this verse on the whole is addressing the people of the scripture: those people who have heard or have been reached by some of the precedent messages. So they also know about this covenant according to the Qur'an and that's what many scholars say: Not only the prophets have to follow a messenger also his followers should follow and support him if the conditions or criteria are met.

See also [What is the meaning of Meethaaq taken from the prophets (Anbiaa)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33674/what-is-the-meaning-of-meethaaq-taken-from-the-prophets-anbiaa/) (Meetaq is Arabic for covenant)

Finally the Qur'an quotes a couple of messengers -mostly by name- (note that all messengers were prophets, as, as explained being a messenger means being a prophet with an extra duty) they might not be more than 30 some ahadith quoted amounts of prophets and amounts of messengers some are more others less reliable. But what is certain is that the amount of messengers is lower than that of prophets. And Allah knows best!

Comment: thanks - nice breakdown :)
just a lil comment
"then there comes to you a messenger confirming what is with you" - here Allah talks about messenger so it must be Messenger that is meeting Prophet. Prophets are humans and Messengers are either Prophet/Humans/Jinn/Angels (ref: 22/75, 6/130)
There is no human or Prophet can go and meet each Prophet. It would be either Angel messenger or Jinn Messenger. We don't know their life span they might be living for hundreds/thousands of years. Shaitan can live thousands of years why can't any other pious Jinn/Angel/Messenger that can meet all Prophets!

Comment: @ikram0459 you seem to insist on a physical meeting while Allah can just inform them via wahy that a Messneger has been sent or they may hear of him. The Messenger doesn't need to go and gather each prophet of his time it works the other way!

Comment: Communication is mentioned in ayat. They said, Allah said, He said....
how you will explain last part:
He said: "Then bear witness; and I am with you among the witnesses (for this)."
who is that HE in this? communication looks like physical meeting, isn't it?

Comment: one more point 
3/41-44 - here Marium(AS) got news from Angels about Isa(AS)
19/16-18 - here Mariums(AS) met angel that looks like human and gave good news.

If Allah can send any Angel that can give news that looks like human, so it may be possible that Allah sent a angel messenger that looks like human that can take covenant / confirmation of scripture and can communicate with Prophet(AS) / Person like Marium(AS). what you think?

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, I would disagree with this part: "Prophets unlike Messengers actually don't have the duty to spread Allah's message, even if they may get revelation (wahy), their duty is to live according to the message at hands and apply it in their daily life and (only) teach it when asked -so they don't need to be actively preaching!"

Because in Bukhari: "he Prophet (ﷺ) once came out to us and said, "Some nations were displayed before me. A prophet would pass in front of me with one man, and another with two men, and another with a group of people. and another with nobody with him."

Comment: @Ahmed and where do you think this disagrees with my words? The hadith actually emphasizes its correctness because, if it was differently they would have a higher amount of "followers" or better "believers" in their company.

Comment: @Medi1Saif You mentioned that a Prophet's job/duty is not to spread ALLAAH's message. However, the hadith states that some Prophets will have followers (various sizes) and some will not have any. So this would indicate that a Prophet's job is to spread whatever knowledge they do have to their people. Not only wait for people to ask them. But to proactively teach it to others.

Comment: @Medi1Saif To elucidate my point. I believe the hadith when it mentions Prophets that will come "with" X number of people or none. The word "with" in my opinion is a reference to followers which are mentioned later in the hadith in reference to Musa and Muhammad (Peace and Blessings Be Upon Them) followers. So I guess it's the way you look at the hadith.

Answer (score 1):

The covenant from the Prophets is essentially also a covenant from their ummah's, and it applies to whoever of them found the Messenger. This is apparent from the next verse:

> فمن تولى بعد ذلك فأولئك هم الفاسقون
>
> And whoever turned away after that - they were the defiantly disobedient.

As it is impossible for Prophets themselves to be disobedient as they are infallible.

Comment: I understood your comment and next ayat, but the question is how come Rasul (Muhammad(S)) went to past prophets and did confirmation and how come all those prophets helped Muhammad(S) ? in arabic text, Nabiyun and Rasul word is mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

**Question** : How come Rasul (Muhammad(S)) went to each Prophet in past and did confirmation and how Prophets of past helped Muhammad(S) as mentioned in ayat?

**Answer** : As an Arabic Speaker I assure you , no where in the original text was the prophet mentioned as being present , this Ayah is Allah describing the covenant that the past prophets took upon themselves and their nations to help and follow prophet Mohammed (PBUH) when he is given the resalah eventually .
So to answer the first part of your question , no where in the Ayah is it mentioned that the prophet is there .
For the second part , here "helping" is a translation of an Arabic word تنصرنه which translates to aiding him against his enemies / to be there for him / to believe in him . And as Uma just clarified in his answer , this covenant was not for the prophets only but for their nations as well , so the promises of helping the prophet and believing in him were to be fulfilled by their nations whom were very much present when prophet Mohammed (PBUH) was given the resalah . (ie Jews,Christians,Abrahimics ,..etc)

Comment: Just like to add my understanding of this ayat:

https://quran.com/7/172 - ....."Am I not your Lord?" They said: "Yes! We testify," lest you should say on the Day of Resurrection: "Verily, we have been unaware of this."
we all say that this took place in heavan / etc that we don't know but it happend. That was covenant with us from Allah and that ayat i mentioned 3/81 in Question is covenant of Prophets with Allah. 

(my comment continues...)

Comment: In 3/81 covenant of Prophets is mentioned not covenant of Messengers (Rasul) and to all Prophets a single Rosul is testifying that they got the Book and wisdom & what is with them (as mentioned in ayat). Idrees(AS) is Prophet how come he got covenant with that Rosul and his people know who to help after 2000 years (1000 years Nuh(AS) lived people say and Idress (AS) lifetime as well) so how come their people know who to help.
(my comment continues...)

Comment: This covenant of Prophets include all prophets, normally a community is with Rosuls in Quran. Rosul is appointed to go to certain community or Clan. Normally Prophet is human in Quran while a Rosul can be human, Rasul can be a Prophet and a Rosul can be angel according to Quranic ayats. Maybe that Rosul was Angel that took covenant with Prophets or maybe that Rosult was Muhammad(S) and we don't know how come he went there (Musadiqalima ma'aa kum) like we don't know how Allah took human's covenant, same way humans don't know how Muhammad(S) went there
(my comment continues...)

Comment: Here https://quran.com/6/83-89 - 18 Prophets name are mentioned and at the end it is said "Those are the ones to whom We gave the alkitab and authority and prophethood". Muhammad(S) name is not mentioned there. 
I think this 3/81 ayat and 6/83-89 is indirectly proving Muhammad(S) as the Seal of the Prophets. As Allah says in https://quran.com/33/40 - " KhatamunNabiyeen" - not khatamurRasuls ... I think Muhammad(S) went to all Prophets (not Rosuls) - normally Rosul is a Prophet but not all Prophets are Rosult). I can b wrong in understanding but that's just my view,plz correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @ikram0459 I am sorry but it seems I really don't understand your question , can you formulate it more clearly please , because I lost track of what you are saying .
Also helps if you just use "messenger" instead of Rasul , it is the same meaning, the usage of Rosuls here really confuses me more .

Comment: its hard to explain again, just replace Rosul with Messenger and read again :) and check my latest reply above for Medi1Saif

Answer (score 0):

Prophet SAW is noor as well as human and was alive before coming in this world and then his nafs tasted death and He SAW is alive now and He SAW is sent as a prophet to entire mankind from first to last as said in the Quran "We have sent thee not, but to mankind entire, good tidings to bear, and warning; but most men do not know it. as well as from hadith

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information on our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please also consider supporting your claims by evidences and read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

In ayat 3:81, Al-Quran mentions a covenant of the prophets with Allah. We will analyze related ayahs in this post.

3:81  وَإِذْ أَخَذَ اللَّهُ مِيثَاقَ النَّبِيِّينَ لَمَا آتَيْتُكُم مِّن كِتَابٍ وَحِكْمَةٍ ثُمَّ جَاءَكُمْ رَسُولٌ مُّصَدِّقٌ لِّمَا مَعَكُمْ لَتُؤْمِنُنَّ بِهِ وَلَتَنصُرُنَّهُ ۚ قَالَ أَأَقْرَرْتُمْ وَأَخَذْتُمْ عَلَىٰ ذَٰلِكُمْ إِصْرِي ۖ قَالُوا أَقْرَرْنَا ۚ قَالَ فَاشْهَدُوا وَأَنَا مَعَكُم مِّنَ الشَّاهِدِينَ

And when Allah took the covenant from the prophets, saying. "That I have given you from book and wisdom; then comes to you a messenger, confirming what is with you; then you do believe in him and render him help." Allah said. "Do you render your consent, and take this my burden on you?" They said. "We agree." He said. "Then bear witness, and I am with you among the witnesses."

3:82 فَمَن تَوَلَّىٰ بَعْدَ ذَٰلِكَ فَأُولَٰئِكَ هُمُ الْفَاسِقُونَ

If any turn back after this, they are perverted transgressors.

A covenant of Allah and His prophets is mentioned in this ayat, that when they get from the Book and Wisdom, then  comes to them a messenger; they should then indeed believe in him and support him. A school of scholars have the view that the messenger mentioned in this ayat is 'Mohammad' (pbuh). However the problem with that view point is that the prophets were sent at different time periods and Mohammad (pbuh) as a 'bashar' and human cannot travel in time to take covenant from other prophets. In addition this covenant is also taken from the messenger Mohammad (pbuh) as per below ayat 33:7.

33:7  وَإِذْ أَخَذْنَا مِنَ النَّبِيِّينَ مِيثَاقَهُمْ وَمِنكَ وَمِن نُّوحٍ وَإِبْرَاهِيمَ وَمُوسَىٰ وَعِيسَى ابْنِ مَرْيَمَ ۖ وَأَخَذْنَا مِنْهُم مِّيثَاقًا غَلِيظًا

And when We took from the prophets their covenant and from you (the messenger pbuh) and from Noah, Abrahim, Mosa, and Essa the son of Mary and We took from them a solemn covenant.

At a few places in Quran, Allah specifically mentioned that the messenger Mohammad pbuh, was not present in the past eras, such as with prophet Moosa (a.s) when Allah called him from the side of Toor. Therefore prophet Mohammad pbuh was not the one present in his era and could not take covenant from other prophets.

28:46  وَمَا كُنتَ بِجَانِبِ الطُّورِ إِذْ نَادَيْنَا وَلَٰكِن رَّحْمَةً مِّن رَّبِّكَ لِتُنذِرَ قَوْمًا مَّا أَتَاهُم مِّن نَّذِيرٍ مِّن قَبْلِكَ لَعَلَّهُمْ يَتَذَكَّرُونَ

You (the messenger pbuh) were not at the side of Tur when We called. Yet a mercy from your Lord, so that you give warning to a people to whom no warner had come before you so that they may remember.

Some scholars hold the view that this covenant took place in the realm of sprit world, when the prophets were not sent to the world yet. But then if that had taken place at that time, the prophet (pbuh) would have known about this covenant and he would have been to previous prophets to take covenant, but the ayat 11:49 says that you (the messenger pbuh) did not know about the the events of previous prophets.

11:49  تِلْكَ مِنْ أَنبَاءِ الْغَيْبِ نُوحِيهَا إِلَيْكَ ۖ مَا كُنتَ تَعْلَمُهَا أَنتَ وَلَا قَوْمُكَ مِن قَبْلِ هَٰذَا ۖ فَاصْبِرْ ۖ إِنَّ الْعَاقِبَةَ لِلْمُتَّقِينَ

Such are some of the stories of the unseen, which We have revealed unto thee, before this, neither thou nor your people knew them. So persevere patiently. for the End is for those who are righteous.

Another school of thought is that the covenant was for prophets including their nations. So when the messenger Mohammad (pbuh) would come to the nations of previous prophets then they should believe in him and support him. However the problem with this view point is that the ayat specifically mentions the covenant of the prophets and does not mention their nations. So, we cannot assume the covenant of prophets to include their nations as well.

It is a no brainer that for a human/bashar to be present in all prophets times and taking covenant from them is not possible. Therefore this messenger mentioned in ayat 3:81 has to be either an angel or Rooh, the Sprit. The angels and Rooh are stated to be messenger in Al-Quran by Allah.

16:2  يُنَزِّلُ الْمَلَائِكَةَ بِالرُّوحِ مِنْ أَمْرِهِ عَلَىٰ مَن يَشَاءُ مِنْ عِبَادِهِ أَنْ أَنذِرُوا أَنَّهُ لَا إِلَٰهَ إِلَّا أَنَا فَاتَّقُونِ

He sends down His angels with sprit for His Command, to such of His servants as He pleases, (saying). "Warn (Man) that there is no god but I. so do your duty unto Me."

The Rooh/Sprit is the spirit of the Words of Quran. Allah mentions sending the Spirit to Mariam a.s which was in the form of human.

19:17  فَاتَّخَذَتْ مِن دُونِهِمْ حِجَابًا فَأَرْسَلْنَا إِلَيْهَا رُوحَنَا فَتَمَثَّلَ لَهَا بَشَرًا سَوِيًّا

Then she took a hijab/veil apart from them, then We sent to her Our Rooh/Spirit. So he was an even example of a human for her.

Before the spirit comes, the prophets don't have the true understanding of the message of Allah.

42:52  وَكَذَٰلِكَ أَوْحَيْنَا إِلَيْكَ رُوحًا مِّنْ أَمْرِنَا ۚ مَا كُنتَ تَدْرِي مَا الْكِتَابُ وَلَا الْإِيمَانُ وَلَٰكِن جَعَلْنَاهُ نُورًا نَّهْدِي بِهِ مَن نَّشَاءُ مِنْ عِبَادِنَا ۚ وَإِنَّكَ لَتَهْدِي إِلَىٰ صِرَاطٍ مُّسْتَقِيمٍ

And Likewise, We have inspired you the Rooh/Spirit from our order, you did not have the perception, what is The Book and the Belief, but We have made it light, We guide with it whom We will from Our servants. And surely you guide towards the straight path.

When the Spirit becomes apparent to the messengers then they are obliged to support it. How to support the spirit, when it comes to them is to respond to it and start spreading the message of Allah to the masses.

5:67  يَا أَيُّهَا الرَّسُولُ بَلِّغْ مَا أُنزِلَ إِلَيْكَ مِن رَّبِّكَ ۖ وَإِن لَّمْ تَفْعَلْ فَمَا بَلَّغْتَ رِسَالَتَهُ ۚ وَاللَّهُ يَعْصِمُكَ مِنَ النَّاسِ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَهْدِي الْقَوْمَ الْكَافِرِينَ

O' Messenger ! proclaim The (message) which has been sent to you from your Lord. If you did not, you would not have proclaimed His message. And Allah will defend you from masses, for Allah guides not the nation of rejecters.

Al-Quran mentions aiding prophet Essa ibne Mariam with Rooh.

2:87  وَلَقَدْ آتَيْنَا مُوسَى الْكِتَابَ وَقَفَّيْنَا مِن بَعْدِهِ بِالرُّسُلِ ۖ وَآتَيْنَا عِيسَى ابْنَ مَرْيَمَ الْبَيِّنَاتِ وَأَيَّدْنَاهُ بِرُوحِ الْقُدُسِ ۗ أَفَكُلَّمَا جَاءَكُمْ رَسُولٌ بِمَا لَا تَهْوَىٰ أَنفُسُكُمُ اسْتَكْبَرْتُمْ فَفَرِيقًا كَذَّبْتُمْ وَفَرِيقًا تَقْتُلُونَ

We gave Moosa the Book and followed him up with a succession of messengers; We gave Essa the son of Mary Clear Signs and strengthened him with the holy spirit. Is it that whenever there comes to you a messenger with what your nafs/soul desire not, you are puffed up with pride?- Some of them you called impostors, and others you slew!

The Spirit is the Messenger to all mankind, past and present and proclaims as such in the below ayat and asks them to believe in the Ummi prophet.

7:158  قُلْ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنِّي رَسُولُ اللَّهِ إِلَيْكُمْ جَمِيعًا الَّذِي لَهُ مُلْكُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ ۖ لَا إِلَٰهَ إِلَّا هُوَ يُحْيِي وَيُمِيتُ ۖ فَآمِنُوا بِاللَّهِ وَرَسُولِهِ النَّبِيِّ الْأُمِّيِّ الَّذِي يُؤْمِنُ بِاللَّهِ وَكَلِمَاتِهِ وَاتَّبِعُوهُ لَعَلَّكُمْ تَهْتَدُونَ

Say. "O Mankind! I am the messenger of Allah,to you all to; to whom belongs the kingdom of the heavens and the earth. There is no god but He. It is He who gives life and death. So believe in Allah and His Messenger, the Ummi Prophet, who believes in Allah and His words. And follow him so that you may be guided."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please note that [signatures are not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38570/295232).