# What does the Quran teach, if anything, about the covenant in Genesis 17?

Tags: quran, reference-request, torah

I’m writing a paper on Genesis 17 and I would love to include the perspective of Islam. Any references do not necessarily have to be from the Quran but they should be from a relatively ancient source.

Here is a link to the passage in question: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+17&version=NIV

Comment: And what does Genesis 17 actually say? We are on Islam.stackexchange not on biblical hermeneutics you can't expect to find bible experts here. Please consider adding any necessary information :). Maybe [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49930/covenant-of-prophets-can-someone-explain-this-ayat) is relevant.

Comment: @Medi1Saif my apologies, I will add a link to the passage

Answer (score 1):

Starting on a tangent but did you know that in Islam there is a Prophet named Zakariyah (aka Priest Zechariah in Bible) who is the father of Prophet Yahya (aka John the Baptist in Bible).

Coming back to your question about [Genesis 17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2017&version=NIV):

**1. Prophet Ibrahim (aka Prophet Abraham in Bible):**

In the Quran, Chapter 2, Verse 124:

> "And [mention, O Muhammad], when Abraham was tried by his Lord with
> commands and he fulfilled them. [ Allah ] said, **"Indeed, I will make
> you a leader for the people."** [Abraham] said, "And of my descendants?"
> [ Allah ] said, "My covenant does not include the wrongdoers."

**2. Sarah bearing a child in old age:**

In the Quran, Chapter 11, Verses 69-73:

> And certainly did Our messengers come to Abraham with good tidings;
> they said, "Peace." He said, "Peace," and did not delay in bringing
> [them] a roasted calf.But when he saw their hands not reaching for it,
> he distrusted them and felt from them apprehension. They said, "Fear
> not. We have been sent to the people of Lot."And his Wife was
> standing, and she smiled. Then We gave her good tidings of Isaac and
> after Isaac, Jacob. She said, "Woe to me! Shall I give birth while I
> am an old woman and this, my husband, is an old man? Indeed, this is
> an amazing thing!" They said, "Are you amazed at the decree of Allah ?
> May the mercy of Allah and His blessings be upon you, people of the
> house. Indeed, He is Praiseworthy and Honorable."

**3. Circumcision of all male believers**

Circumcision is not mentioned in the Quran but is highlighted in many Hadiths

> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said "The Prophet) Abraham circumcised himself
> after he had passed the age of eighty years and he circumcised himself
> with an axe." **Sahih al-Bukhari,Book 79, Hadith 70**

and

> Ibn Shihab said, "When a man became Muslim, he was ordered to have himself circumcised, >even if he was old." **Al-Adab Al-Mufrad, Book 1, Hadith 1252**

and

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as having said that Ibrahim (as) circumcised >himself with the help of an adze when he was eighty years old.
> **Sahih Muslim, Book 43, Hadith 199**

There are many more Hadiths like the one below which state that circumcision is part of human nature for a male believer:

Narrated Abu Huraira:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said "Five things are in accordance with Al Fitra : to
> be circumcised, to shave the pelvic region, to pull out the hair of
> the armpits, to cut short the moustaches, and to clip the nails."
> **Sahih al-Bukhari, Book 79, Hadith 69**

There are many similarities between Judaism, Christianity and Islam. Unfortunately, we humans choose to concentrate on what's different and fight over it :)

> Say, "O People of the Book, come to a word that is equitable between
> us and you - that we will not worship except God and not associate
> anything with Him and not take other as gods instead of God."
> But if they turn away, then say, "Bear witness that we are Muslims
> [submitting to Him]." **Quran 3:64**

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me what a Hadith is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith

Comment: In short, Hadiths are documented sayings & actions (Sunnah) of the Prophet Muhammad. But a majority of these were documented atleast 150 years after his death. The authenticity is validated against the chain of narrators from the speaker all the way back to the Prophet.